# SP511E + TTP223 Swapping tactile switch for capacitive touchpad

Tags: led, led-strip

I'm new to electronics and I'm a little bit lost here.

I am making a lightbox powered by a 12V power supply, an SP511E wifi controller and a LED Strip. Everything will be inside the wooden lightbox (only the power cable will go out of the box by a canal to plug it to the outlet).

I need to add an external switch to be able to turn it on/off when there is no internet.

The SP511E already has a physical power button, but it will be inside the lightbox, which will be closed with screws.

[image: SP511E tactile switch]

I want to swap the internal tactile button for a TTP223 capacitive touch switch (or just add it if removing the tactile button is not necessary) because it would be neat to only touch a certain area on the box to turn it on.

[image: TTP223]

The thing is that I have no idea how to do it. Could somebody please instruct me on what I need and how to do the connections?

I can solder and have multimeter.

TTP223 Module Schematic
[image]

I appreciate your help and thank you in advance. I tried to compile all the info on this post, but if you need any more info please tell me. Unfortunately I haven't find the SP511E module schematic.

Greetings.

SP511E from the other side
[image: SP511E top side]

TTP223 IC Datasheet: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1179638/TTELEC/TTP223-XXX.html

TTP223 Module Schematic + Info:
https://www.epitran.it/ebayDrive/datasheet/23.pdf

Comment: Please provide a link to a datasheet for the TTP223 module.

Comment: @PeterBennett Here it is: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/1179638/TTELEC/TTP223-XXX.html

Comment: You need the datasheet or schematic of the TTP223 module you are using, not (just) for the IC itself.

Comment: @PeterBennett This is the one: https://www.epitran.it/ebayDrive/datasheet/23.pdf I deleted the other comments to avoid misleading.